# What does it mean to let $m\to \infty$ for $P\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=m+1}^{\infty}A_k\right)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am currently reading a proof that seems to argue that as $m\to \infty$, we get that $P\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=m+1}^{\infty}A_k\right)$ will yield $P(A_n, \text{i.o.})$. I don't see why that is the case. Could someone elaborate?

This is what is to be proved, it's $(2)$:

[image]

It uses the Chung-Erdos inequality and argues here:

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to add some more details, like what proof / book / etc.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-35513-7_7, Proof of Theorem 1.

Comment: I don't think that the rest of the proof will be helpful for the question. But it might be helpful if my interpretation is wrong.

Comment: Added some pictures. But I'm note sure I can share the entire proof. (Copyright?)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a consequence of continuity from above for probability measures:
$$P(A_n \, \mathrm{ i.o.})= P \left( \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=m+1}^\infty A_k \right) = \lim_{m \to \infty} P \left( \bigcup_{k=m+1}^\infty A_k \right)$$

Comment: I see, didn't think about that. Ty.